# My Xeon Processor supports VT-x, is it compatible with Xen?

Tags: virtualization, hardware, xen, xeon

While looking for a server to run Xen I stumbled across a barebones setup which comes with an **Intel Xeon L5420** on the **SuperMicro X7DCA-L** motherboard. Doing a bit of research I found the processor supports VT-x but I'm not sure if that guarantees Xen will work. What do I need to look for when shopping for motherboards or hardware in general?

- Processor details: http://intel.ly/sHfoFn
- Motherboard details: http://bit.ly/LrUnn2

Comment: Do you need HVM or paravirtual to work? Paravirtual will, in any case. BTW, the hardware is relatively mature, are you planning on buying it used/surplus?

Comment: Yeah, eBay. Would paravirtual work on any hardware?

Comment: Xen will work with VT-x http://xen.org/files/Marketing/WhatisXen.pdf

Comment: This question was closed because shopping recommendations are outside of the scope of Server Fault. [Please ensure you are familiar with the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Disagree with the close. Here, the question is about *experience with specific* mature hardware that the requester already made sure he can buy. The regional and time factors don't matter here. And yes, paravirtual will work on a Pentium 3 probably. Just beware of chipset/BIOS bugs they can still give you a lot of headache with any VM system.